# Conditional replacement of column in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I`m currently stuck on writing some script in numpy, which main goal is to be efficient (so, vectorization is **mandatory**).

Let`s assume 3-d array:

```
arr = [[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 4],
        [0, 0, 3, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 4],
        [0, 0, 3, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 3, 4],
        [0, 0, 3, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

My goal is to set to dismiss every column which have more than one number other than zero. So, having above matrix the result should be something like:

```
filtered = [[[0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 4],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 0]],

            [[0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [1, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]],

            [[0, 2, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]],

            [[0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

I`ve managed to work this around by set of np.count_nonzero, np.repeat and reshape:

```
indices = np.repeat(np.count_nonzero(a=arr, axis=1), repeats=4, axis=0).reshape(4, 4, 4)
result = indices * a
```

Which produces good results but looks like missing the point (there is a lot of cryptic matrix shape manipulation only to slice array properly). Furthermore, I`d wish this function to be flexible enough to work out with other axes too (for rows e.g.), resulting:

```
rows_fil = [[[0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 3, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]],

            [[0, 0, 3, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]],

            [[0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 3, 0]],

            [[0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Is there any "numpy" way to achieve such flexible function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to cover a generic axis param -

```
def mask_nnzcount(a, axis):
    # a is input array
    mask = (a!=0).sum(axis=axis, keepdims=True)>1
    return np.where(mask, 0, a)
```

The trick really is at `keepdims = True` which allows us to have a generic solution.

With a 3D array, for your column-fill, that's with `axis=1` and for row-fill it's `axis=2`.

For a generic ndarray, you might want to use `axis=-2` for column-fill and `axis=-1` for row-fill.

Alternatively, we could also use element-wise multiplication instead at the last step to get the output with `a*(~mask)`. Or get an inverted mask i.e. say `inv_mask = (a!=0).sum(axis=axis, keepdims=True)<=1` and then do `a*inv_mask`.